# Generate Entities from existing (MSSQL) database

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I need to connect Symfony2 with our MSSQL Server.

We have installed Apache in Ubuntu with PHP 5.3 and pdo_dblib, so I have installed the bundle [LSWDoctrinePdoDblib](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswDoctrinePdoDblib) following the instructions

My app/config/config.yml looks like:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        #driver:   %database_driver%
        driver_class:   Lsw\DoctrinePdoDblib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
        host:     %database_host%
        #host:     mssql_freetds
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

And my app/config/parameters.yml (with fake data):

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_dblib
    database_host: 10.0.0.33
    database_port: '1433'
    database_name: DB_CONECTAR
    database_user: user_dba
```

I have been following the instructions from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) and when I run the command:

```
 php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/DBP/GestionWSBundle/Resources/config/doctrine --from-database --force
```

Then I get the next error, but the SQL showed there works ok.

```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT    col.name,
                            type.name AS type,
                            col.max_length AS length,
                            ~col.is_nullable AS notnull,
                            def.definition AS [default],
                            col.scale,
                            col.precision,
                            col.is_identity AS autoincrement,
                            col.collation_name AS collation
                  FROM      sys.columns AS col
                  JOIN      sys.types AS type
                  ON        col.user_type_id = type.user_type_id
                  JOIN      sys.objects AS obj
                  ON        col.object_id = obj.object_id
                  LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints def
                  ON        col.default_object_id = def.object_id
                  AND       col.object_id = def.parent_object_id
                  WHERE     obj.type = 'U'
                  AND       obj.name = 'MAILING_LISTS'':

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4004] (severity 16) [SELECT    col.name,
                            type.name AS type,
                            col.max_length AS length,
                            ~col.is_nullable AS notnull,
                            def.definition AS [default],
                            col.scale,
                            col.precision,
                            col.is_identity AS autoincrement,
                            col.collation_name AS collation
                  FROM      sys.columns AS col
                  JOIN      sys.types AS type
                  ON        col.user_type_id = type.user_type_id
                  JOIN      sys.objects AS obj
                  ON        col.object_id = obj.object_id
                  LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints def
                  ON        col.default_object_id = def.object_id
                  AND       col.object_id = def.parent_object_id
                  WHERE     obj.type = 'U'
                  AND       obj.name = 'MAILING_LISTS']
```

Any idea of what can  i do? Thank you very much in advance!!

As I mentioned I am using https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswDoctrinePdoDblib And as you can read at the end of the website he try to do the same and did:

- Map any non-compatible column types to string
- Hack the Doctrine core to skip any tables without primary keys

Do you know how can I do that? I dont know even how to look for that information.

Comment: I guess you have a typo in your `xml` scheme. Check your syntax again and remove any `~`.

Comment: should I generate any xml scheme? I thought that doing this Symfony will generate all the entities with them code. I have nothing in ./src/DBP/GestionWSBundle/Resources/config/doctrine

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the `xml` generation. Have you tried another scheme instead? like `yml`?

Comment: I've tried yml but got the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments of the documention of [pdo-dblib in php.net](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-dblib.php) I've found that the DB-Library doesn't support unicode, so if the SQL have a field of type ntext|nvarchar|etc it gives the error 4004.

So I go to the place where is the "bad" SQL and cast all fields (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/SQLServerPlatform.php) to another type:

```
public function getListTableColumnsSQL($table, $database = null)
{
    return "SELECT    CAST(col.name AS text) as name,
                      CAST(type.name AS text) AS type,
                      CAST(col.max_length AS real) AS length,
                      cast(~col.is_nullable as bit) AS notnull,
                      cast(def.definition as bit) AS [default],
                      cast(col.scale as real) as scale,
                      cast(col.precision as real) as precision,
                      cast(col.is_identity as bit) AS autoincrement,
                      cast(col.collation_name as text) AS collation
            FROM      sys.columns AS col
            JOIN      sys.types AS type
            ON        col.user_type_id = type.user_type_id
            JOIN      sys.objects AS obj
            ON        col.object_id = obj.object_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints def
            ON        col.default_object_id = def.object_id
            AND       col.object_id = def.parent_object_id
            WHERE     obj.type = 'U'
            AND       obj.name = '$table'";
}
```

This is a temporary solution, I will like to incorporate it to a bundle or something, but now I really don't have any idea of how to make a bundle or how I should modify this in a correct way so as soon as I know I will share the information here.

Doing this I got the xml with all the table metadata.

Answer (score 1):

In freetds configuration file (/etc/freetds/freetds.conf) replace

```
[global]
       tds version = 4.2
```

with:

```
[global]
        tds version = 8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

in /etc/freetds.conf :

```
;tds version = 4.2
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

In php.ini :

```
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

This issue is because of character encoding.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Please be careful when you change the default_charset  it may cause issue in existing special character encoding and decoding if you are working on and exiting project. if its a new project then its not an issue